# fileinput - indexing lines out of order

Tags: python

I have got a huge txt file. I cannot use readlines() to read it because Memory error appeared, so I have started to use fileinput.
 It works well until I need to write some of its lines into another file, then I got  "accessing lines out of order". 
here is that part of my script:

```
input_4=fileinput.input([plik0_a])
out=open('out_file','w')
for i in range(s,e):
    out.writelines('%s' % input[i])
```

Please help me to find a way to write lines, which number is == i.
I assume that it is not difficult but I am just a beginner:).

I need something that will work like that(part of script below) with huge file.

```
n=10918 
s=(int(start)-n) 
e=(int(end)-n+1)                                                
czyta_4=open(plik0_a,'r') 
zczyta_4=czyta_4.readlines()
for i in range(s,e):
  out.writelines('%s' % i +': '+ '%s' % zczyta_4[i])
```

The result that I get (and I want to get with a huge file, is presented below):

```
0: fixedStep chrom=chr1 start=10918 step=1
1: 0.064 
2: 0.058 
3: 0.064 
4: 0.058 
5: 0.064 
6: 0.064 
7: 0.064 
8: 0.064 
9: 0.064 
10: 0.058
.
.
.
s : 0.058
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use fileinput, the file object is iterable

```
import itertools
with open(plik0_a) as input_4, open('out_file','w') as out:
    out.writelines(itertools.islice(input_4, s, e))
```

Note that the file will be pointing just after line `e`, so you'll have to subtract that if you want to islice some more lines.

eg

```
import itertools
with open(plik0_a) as input_4, open('out_file','w') as out:
    out.writelines(itertools.islice(input_4, 10, 20)) # lines 11-20
    out.writelines(itertools.islice(input_4, 10, 20)) # lines 31-40
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

```
import itertools
input_4=fileinput.input([plik0_a])
out=open('out_file','w')
out.writelines(itertools.islice(input_4, s, e))
```

You may not need `fileinput` at all, if you're dealing with a single file - files can be directly iterated on without loading the whole thing into memory.  Although it can still be awfully convenient for specifying a file on the command line.  For the sake of demonstration:

```
import itertools
with open('in_file','r') as input_4:
    with open('out_file', 'w') as out:
        out.writelines(itertools.islice(input_4, s, e))
```

To include the original line number in the output, use `enumerate`.  This will yield tuples of the line number and the line itself.  It would look something like this:

```
import itertools
input_4=fileinput.input([plik0_a])
out=open('out_file','w')
for (line_number, line) in itertools.islice(enumerate(input_4), s, e):
    out.write('%s: %s' % (line_number, line))
```

Or, using a generator expression:

```
import itertools
input_4=fileinput.input([plik0_a])
out=open('out_file','w')
out.writelines(('%s: %s' % (line_number, line) for (line_number, line) in itertools.islice(enumerate(input_4), s, e)))
```

`enumerate` returns an iterator, so you can `islice` it as well.  By default it starts at 0, which your example shows is probably what you want, but on 2.6 and later it accepts an optional `start` parameter so you could start it at 1 if you prefer.

Comment: Is it possible to write to a file also line number using itertools and islice??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Are you trying to insert lines partway through a file or something?

Comment: I have added better explanation of what I want to get in a question at the top of that page .

Comment: Ah, so you want to include the file line number in the output?

Comment: Edited in an efficient way to do that.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, you may wish to accept an answer as explained here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: So if I like to start from other number than 0, e.g 1500, how can I use this 'start' parameter?

Comment: The `start` parameter determines only the point `enumerate` starts counting from.  EG `enumerate(range(0,10), start=5)` would yield `(5, 0)` as its first tuple, then `(6, 1)`, etc.  Also, reviewing `fileinput` I was reminded that it has a `filelineno()` method that will return the 1-indexed line of the current file that it has just yielded - you could use that instead of `enumerate`. http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.filelineno

Comment: I need to write to a file 0th line with number 1500 instead of 0, first line with 1501 instead 1, second with 1502 instead 2 and so on? How can I do it?

Comment: Assuming you're on 2.6 or higher, `enumerate(input_4, start=1500)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
outfile=open('outfile.txt', 'w')
line=[]
for a in infile:
    line.append(a)
outfile.write(line[number of line to be printed])

## example: If you want to print first line
## outfile.write(line[0])
## outfile.write(line[1]) ## for second line
## if you have a list of lines to be printed
infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
outfile=open('outfile.txt', 'w')
line=[]
for a in infile:
    line.append(a)
line_list =[] ## list of line numbers
for b in line_list:
    outfile.write(line[b])
```

Comment: I guess you want to print specific lines from a file.

Comment: when I just remove readlines, then I got: TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Try changing this step below:
zczyta_4=czyta_4.readlines()
To: for zczyta_4 in czyta_4: